# append timestamp to Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp, append

I like to append to my Dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'ID', 0 ,1,2]`
the row `df.append(i[0], i[1])`. And `i[0]` is a timestamp.

This will lead to error

> cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**df.append**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append) takes `DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'ID', 0 ,1,2])
df = df.append([{'date': i[0], 'ID': i[1]}])
print(df)
```